# An error appears during sqlalchemy_schemadisplay.create_schema_graph call

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a diagram of a database with sqlalchemy_schemadisplay usage.

```
from sqlalchemy_schemadisplay import create_schema_graph
graph = create_schema_graph(metadata=MetaData("db/db.sqlite"))
graph.write_png("db.png")
```

and the following error appears:

TypeError: MetaData.reflect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bind'

Where is the issue?